# Job scheduler to run every day

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a backup of a Mysql database or table every day. So I would like to write a scheduler which will run automatically every day at that particular time.

Can someone please provide the code of how this can be done?

Comment: What OS is your database running on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix/Linux/BSD server, you want to read about [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If it's a Windows server, you want to read about [scheduled tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler). This way, you can have a piece of code be executed every day. I would suggest not doing this with PHP, as mysqldump is much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this on a unix based system would work. For more info see some [cron](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) documentation and [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) documentation

```
 0 0 * * *  /usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername dbname -p password > /home/uesrname/backup.sql
```

If you're on Windows get the MySQL GUI tools. It has a backup scheduler http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CRON jobs. Google will be a good start.